# How much is/are the pens?

Tags: questions, singular-vs-plural

When asking the price of something, do we say:

- *How much **is** the pens?* or
- *How much **are** the pens?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A verb's number (singular or plural) follows the noun it describes.

In your case,

> How much are the pens?

is correct. "Pens" is plural, so therefore "are" must be too. To use "is", you must be only trying to buy one pen:

> How much is the pen?

Comment: I had thought that maybe " how much is the pens?" is a short form for "how much is the cost of the pens?" But the cost of is deleted maybe because it's understood from the context

Comment: @AhmedAyman in that case, "cost" in the noun. "Cost" is singular, so the verb becomes singular. "Of the pens" simply describes "cost" - you could say "How much is the cost" and it makes grammatical but not logical sense.

Comment: @Ahmed No native speaker would interpret the sentence as omitting the word *cost* or the words *cost of*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, clara. You asserted stephen's answer. Thank you, stephan!